# Illustrator: gradient stroke artefacts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, stroke, drop-shadow, gradient-mesh

I am currently trying to recreate the "drop shadow" appearance effect as a vector. As suggested by [this](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-100-vector-drop-shadow-with-illustrator-cs6--vector-5669) tutorial, I tried supplementing the benefits of stroke-gradients. While it did work with other objects of my project the following trees are giving me some troubles:

[image: Illustration of two trees]

Especially at the ends of the branches artefacts are visible:

[image: end of branch with shadow-artefacts]

When further analysing the mesh illustrator is using for the shadows the problem becomes clear:

[image]

the lines of the mesh weirdly follow a circle pattern which isn't much of a surprise given that I made the stroke have round corners, however they kind of seem to be overzealous doing that, actually breaking with the flow those lines should have.

I have also tried changing corner- and cap-properties of the stroke, however to no avail.

Editing the mesh itself also proves to be difficult, up to impossible, since illustrator slows to a crawl whenever I expand the appearance (probably because of the many vector points the mesh creates). Does anybody here maybe know a different approach to creating a vectorised shadow which would be viable for the more complex form of these trees? Or maybe some solution as to how I may avoid the weird mesh behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From a *branch* copy, add a stroke as wide as the shadow will be, aligned outside

[image: stroke]

- **Menu Object** > **Expand Appearance**
- Keep only the outer and inner line of the shape

[image: Expand appearance]

- **Menu Object** > **Compound Path** > **Release**
- Select both shapes and fill them with black 100%
- Select the outer shape > send it to back > **Transparency Panel** > Opacity = 0%

[image: Transparency]

- Select both shapes > **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options**  > **Specified Steps** = 150

[image: blend]

- Align the *shadow blend* behind the *branch*
- Set the *shadow blend* **Blend Mode** to **Multiply**, and change the opacity

[image: Shadow]

**Result**

[image: Branch with shadow]